# In Angular how do I get the ngModuleRef for the module I'm in when I want to dynamically create a component?

Tags: angular, angular-module

Consider a module created like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  providers: [ AdService ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AdBannerComponent,
    HeroJobAdComponent,
    HeroProfileComponent,
    AdDirective
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I want to get the ngModuleRef for the AppModule so that I can pass it in as an option argument to the createComponent function like this:

```
viewContainerRef.createComponent<AdComponent>(addItem.component,{ngModuleRef:myModuleRef<unknown>})
```

Is this possible? If so, how do I get the ngModuleRef to do it?

Comment: I don't think you need to worry about passing in the ngModuleRef option unless you're dynamically loading the module. If your createComponent call is being made in one of the components declared in AppModule, then the AppModule is going to be the default ngModuleRef

Answer (score 4):

If you are dynamically loading the module, this is how you would do it.

```
const { AppModule } = await import(`PATH_TO_MODULE_TS`);
const ngModuleRef = createNgModuleRef(AppModule) // createNgModuleRef is from @angular/core
```

optionally, you can pass an `Injector` as a second parameter to `createNgModuleRef` if you need to define providers, or you could also pass an injector in the options of the `createComponent` method.